# Python 2.7: find item comparing item in a list ignoring cases

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a exlist

```
exList = [['green','apple','NO'],['red','apple','nO'], ['watermellon','red','no'],['honeymellon','yellow','yes']]
```

I want to check the third value in the each sub list to see if it's equal to no matter what case it is.

```
for i in exlist:
   if i[2] == "no":
        print True
   else:
       print False
```

Comment: do `i[2].lower()` to make it all lowercase, then compare it to `'no'`

Comment: already tried that doesnt work

Comment: @saalahdin, its working for me in this example: https://repl.it/FTZQ/0. You could chain a `replace(" ","")` to remove any spaces as well

Comment: oh, i was doing if i[2].lower == "no"  but, this works thank you if str(i[2]).lower()

Comment: @saalahdin you shouldn't have to do `str(i[2])`, `i[2]` is already a string.  The only thing you were missing was calling the function with `lower()`

Comment: and how would you check if the first value in the first list is in the other lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exList = [['green','apple','NO'], ['red','apple','nO'], ['watermellon','red','no'], ['honeymellon','yellow','yes']]

for sublist in exList:
    if sublist[2].lower() == 'no':
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: that doenst work, but someone just showed me the right way                    if str(i[2]).lower()

Comment: It's already a string though.  str(i[2]) doesn't make a difference from just i[2].

Answer (score -1):

If you want compare two strings case insensitive, you can use `lower()` function or `re.search`.

> re.search scans through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern;

The `re.IGNORECASE` param instead, allows to match the strings case insensitive.

Following an example:

```
import re

list = [['green','apple','NO'],['red','apple','nO'],['watermellon','red','no'],['honeymellon','yellow','yes']]

for sub_list in list:
    if re.search('no', sub_list[2], re.IGNORECASE):
        print True
    else:
        print False
```